# Generate documentation from EJB3.0 annotations

Tags: jakarta-ee, annotations, ejb-3.0, documentation-generation

We are implementing a Java EE application and we use EJB3.0 annotations extensively to define session beans, message-driven beans, and inject JMS and JDBC dependency objects.

I would like to find a tool similar to javadoc compiler (not to code one off-the-shelf) that would generate a summary documentation with a summary listing of the beans defined in the EJB modules, their dependencies, and maybe generate deployment plan snippets for easy copy & paste & override. (We use Websphere Community Edition 3.0).

The primary use of this documentation will be by the people that will deploy and bring the application into the production to review its dependencies and prepare for the actual deployment.